# Angular ngFor to loop over dictionary

Tags: angular

I've got a C# API that's returning a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the `<option>`s of a `<select>`.

In Angular it becomes a class variable in the component that I'm making for the `<select>` as:

```
options: { [id: string]: string };
```

(which is a guess -- should I be using some other type?)

How can I loop over this to make the `<option>` tags?

This doesn't work

```
<option ngFor="let o of options | keyvalue" [value]="o.key" [selected]="value === o.key"> {{ o.value }}</option>
```

This is unsatisfactory becuase of the extra `.value` and furthermore everthing has `"` round it

```
<p *ngFor="let o of options | keyvalue"> {{ foo(o.value.key) }}/{{ foo(o.value.value) }}</p>
```

Comment: please provide a stackblitz

Comment: I am not sure how you are retrieving the options, but maybe you need to use `async` to wait for the response to resolve: `*ngFor="let o of options | async | keyvalue"`

Comment: Your `ngFor` is missing the asterisk. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the KeyValue interface from @angular/common and load your data into it.

component.ts

```
options: KeyValue<string, string>[] = [
    {
        key: "first",
        value: "blue"
    },
    {
        key: "second",
        value: "green"
    },
    {
        key: "third",
        value: "yellow"
    }
];
```

component.html

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.key" [selected]="value === option.key">
        {{ option.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In the html file, key and value should be whatever the property names are on your returned options dictionary (case sensitive).